# Stopping a rollback from deleting registry keys if its a 2nd or 3rd install

Tags: inno-setup

I have an installer and have been handling upgrades just by installing over the top of the last install. This works just fine but I noticed that if it is the 2nd or 3rd or whatever install and something fails when the files are being written and a rollback is performed then any registry entries are deleted.

So is it possible to have INNO restore the previous keys?

My code looks like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT"; Flags: noerror
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "pathSvr"; ValueData: "{app}"; Flags: noerror uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "pathResp"; ValueData: "{code:GetResponseDir}"; Flags:  noerror uninsdeletekey;    
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "unInstallerEXE"; ValueData: "unins000.exe"; Flags:  noerror uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "path2PrevInstalls"; ValueData: "{app}"; Flags:  noerror uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "softwareName"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}"; Flags:  noerror uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\NGT\i2tApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "currentVersion"; ValueData: "{#MyAppVersion}"; Flags:  noerror uninsdeletekey
```

I have tried different flags but it seems to me I might have to hand code this. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to undo the delete of registry keys?

Comment: Yes. I am thinking I need to save them somewhere.

Comment: OK, I handled this by saving the reg keys elsewhere and if it was a rollback I just restored them.